# Proxying of document.cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, proxy, javascript-objects

I need to log setting of document.cookie. I can not redefine cookie property just with `document.cookie = {...}` So I need to get setter for document.cookie. But `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(document, "cookie")` returns `undefined`.

UPD. While I was writing the question I found a working solution, but it uses deprecated `__lookupGetter__` and `__lookupSetter__` methods. Is there any solution which doesn't use obsolete API?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The standardized way of accessing getters and setters is with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, but as the name suggests, it only looks on the objects own properties (it does not look up the prototype chain). `document` is an instance of `HTMLDocument`, which inherits from `Document`. In modern browsers the `cookie` property is defined on `Document.prototype`, whereas in older versions of Firefox it is defined on `HTMLDocument.prototype`.

```
var cookieDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'cookie') ||
                 Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLDocument.prototype, 'cookie');
if (cookieDesc && cookieDesc.configurable) {
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
        get: function () {
            return cookieDesc.get.call(document);
        },
        set: function (val) {
            console.log(val);
            cookieDesc.set.call(document, val);
        }
    });
}
```

<s>Ironically, in the most privacy-concerned browser Safari, the descriptor has set `configurable` to *false* and does not contain the getter nor setter, and neither does `__lookupGetter__` or `__lookupSetter__`. So I haven't found a way to override `document.cookie` in Safari yet (8.0.8 on OS X and iOS 9.0.2). WebKit nightly acts the same way as Safari, so it doesn't seem to get fixed anytime soon.</s>

**Update October 2019:** Tested the above code in Safari 12.1.2 on MacOS Mojave, and `cookieDesk` is now configurable! This means my [proof of concept `document.cookie` protection](https://github.com/finn-no/cookie-police) from 2015 might actually work now :)

Comment: The new versions of firefox define it on `Document` just like the rest of the Browsers. Should still keep the comment in the answer, just as a heads-up

Comment: @PatrickHollweck Thanks for the heads up! Updated the answer to reflect the change in Firefox.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this solution, it works great for many cookies, but not for all. For example, the cookie "_fbp" set by this script: https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/..........?v=2.9.43&r=stable seems not to be covered with this solution. Any Idea why?

Comment: @nikelone your link is wrong but I would assume they're using an iframe to set that cookie, the way here only works for window.top. Adding this to dynamically created iframes is still possible but would need you to do much more prototype overwriting...

Answer (score 1):

While I was writing the question I found next code solves my problem:

```
var cookie_setter_orig = document.__lookupSetter__("cookie").bind(document);
var cookie_getter_orig = document.__lookupGetter__("cookie").bind(document);
Object.defineProperty(document, "cookie", {
  get: function () {
    return cookie_getter_orig();
  },
  set: function (val) {
    console.log(val);
    cookie_setter_orig(val);
  }
});
```

But I don't like using deprecated methods, so I hope there is a better solution.