# How to disable cookies in a generic way till cookies are accepted by user

Tags: javascript, http, magento, cookies

Is there a fancy way to disable cookies untill the user accepts them?

Following Problem: I have a webshop which uses quite a lot cookies and in order to be GDPR conform we need to "disable" cookies untill the user has accepted them. **I do not want to rewrite the whole shop system** and therefore I am searching for a generic solution.

My aproach is:

- unset all `set-cookie` headers sent by our server (via nginx or php)

But there are still some problems:

- how can I prevent external sites from setting cookies without completely removing them (bing, google, fb, ..)
- how can I prevent **javascript** from setting cookies without modifying all javascript sources (is it possible to override the browser functions so you can't set cookies via JS)

Comment: How is google, bing, etc. setting cookies on your site?

Comment: e.g.: adform (an ad-network) is setting cookies via set-cookie header in xhr requests

Comment: i think bing and google are setting them via javascript

Comment: JS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33064438/2068362

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If GDPR compliance is your concern, just removing cookies won't be enough. You need to disable any tracking scripts collecting personally identifiable information (PII).

I recommend moving all tracking scripts to Google Tag Manger, and using the methods outlined by Simo Ahava. [Guide 1](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/respect-opt-out-from-advertising-and-analytics/) and [Guide 2](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/opt-out-of-google-analytics-tracking/). His methods don't work great for tracking tags that aren't Google, but with a custom trigger you can stop anything.

That being said, if you do just want to remove cookies, this should do it.

```js
function deleteCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < theCookies.length; i++) {
        document.cookie = theCookies[i].split('=')[0] + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. my approach is now to wrap all tracking scripts and add them to a job queue. when the user accepts cookies i execute the jobs in the job queue. but yes... i also thought of GTM, but the problem in my case was, that the php module is rendering the javascript (setting product id, quantity, ...) and therefore i would have to move that logic to javascript

Answer (score 6):

For disabling JS-Cookies you may use:

```
if(!document.__defineGetter__) {
Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
    get: function(){return ''},
    set: function(){return true},
});
} else {
    document.__defineGetter__("cookie", function() { return '';} );
    document.__defineSetter__("cookie", function() {} );
}
```

Comment: Nice. But any idea how to enable them again after this?

Comment: you may store the original getter and setter functions in a variable and when enable them again you could set the getters and setters to the original functions, or you simply reload the page and do not override the functions again

Comment: I tried to make it work with the variables, but somehow it did't want to. So I used the latter solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My approach (not entirely an answer to your question, but perhaps an alternative to yoru question) is to tell the users that my site has cookies, and they have to 'deal with it' if they want to continue to use my site. Of course, this may not work for your site.

I put a notice at the top (with code from https://cookieconsent.insites.com/ as a start), which will show on all pages until they accept (explicit consent from them).

You could use a button to delete all cookies, but then you can't use my site until you accept them again. But that protocol will keep me in compliance.

Comment: yes thats our current solution before GDPR. But this solution is not entirely GDPR conform because you store cookies BEFORE the user accepts them, even if the user does not realize this because you delete the cookies afterwards

Comment: The code used in the reference site displays the 'OK' button, but does not store the cookie until visitor clicks 'ok'. And will continue to display the GDPR message until visitor clicks 'ok'. So the code is GDPR-compliant (IMHO), unless you are storing other cookies in your pages.

Comment: ah ok... i thought you are storing the cookies at the beginning and if he declines them you delete them