# HTML/JavaScript disable cookies

Tags: javascript, html, session-cookies

Nice to meet you.
I have some problem.

How to HTML or JavaScript disable cookies?

All Internet's answer is expired time set to yesterday.
Like under the code.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
var willCookie = '';
willCookie += 'CookieName=Value';
willCookie += 'expires' + date.toUTCString();
document.cookie = willCookie;
```

How to don't create cookies in HTML or JavaScript? not browser.

Comment: DO you want to disable the cookie feature for your website.., ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will block if the cookie is being set

```
if(!document.__defineGetter__) {
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
        get: function(){return ''},
        set: function(){return true},
    });
} else {
    document.__defineGetter__("cookie", function() { return '';} );
    document.__defineSetter__("cookie", function() {} );
}
```

For PHP:

```
$dirty = false;
foreach(headers_list() as $header) {
    if($dirty) continue; // I already know it needs to be cleaned
    if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie/',$header)) $dirty = true;
}
if($dirty) {
    $phpversion = explode('.',phpversion());
    if($phpversion[1] >= 3) {
        header_remove('Set-Cookie'); // php 5.3
    } else {
        header('Set-Cookie:'); // php 5.2
    }        
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// remember, these are the possible parameters for Set_Cookie:
// name, value, expires, path, domain, secure
Set_Cookie( 'test', 'none', '', '/', '', '' );
// if Get_Cookie succeeds, cookies are enabled, since 
//the cookie was successfully created.
if ( Get_Cookie( 'test' ) )
{
    document.write( 'cookies are currently enabled.' );
    /* 
    this is an example of a set cookie variable, if 
    you want to use this on the page or on another script 
    instead of writing to the page you would just check that value
    for true or false and then do what you need to do.
    */
    cookie_set = true;
    // and these are the parameters for Delete_Cookie:
    // name, path, domain
    // make sure you use the same parameters in Set and Delete Cookie.
    Delete_Cookie('test', '/', '');
}
// if the Get_Cookie test fails, cookies are not enabled for this session.
else {
    document.write('cookies are not currently enabled.');
    cookie_set = false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: At least on chrome, if I leave the cookieSetter line enabled, it will still disable cookieGetter...

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
cookieExpire = new Date();

cookieExpire.setMonth(cookieExpire.getMonth() + 10);
```

Also check this link:
[Is it possible to block cookies from being set using Javascript or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306254/is-it-possible-to-block-cookies-from-being-set-using-javascript-or-php)